# How to remove posts from a static homepage in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am making a site with wordpress. I changed my homepage to static, But it still shows the posts on it.

How do i remove them?

Comment: Please follow to ask good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If still front page shows blog posts listing in static front page then, most probably theme is not supporting the front page settings properly.

Answer (score 0):

On your site dashboard, go to Settings > Reading and change "Your homepage displays" to "A static page (select below)". Next, select your page.